# threads behaviour on multiple locks of the same mutex

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

If I lock the same mutex in two different places in my function, and a context switch occurs when one thread is in one of them, and the second thread gets to the other one, will it be blocked?

I'll try to give a simple example of what I mean, maybe it will be clearer.
Say I have the following code in a file test.c

```
int globalVar = 0;    

void testMutex(pthread_mutex_t myMutex) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
    globalVar++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);

    printf("%s \n", "Doing some other stuff here");

    pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
    globalVar--;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
}
```

and in a different file main.c, I have a main function which create two threads, `thread1` and `thread2`, both running `testMutex` function. 
`thread1` is executed first, and while in the second part of the function (the -- part, after `printf`), before mutex is unlocked, `thread2` start running, from the function beginning.
will `thread2` be able to execute `globalVar++`, or will it stay blocked, waiting for the mutex to be unlocked?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is "yes".

The [pthread_mutex_lock documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) makes this pretty clear:

> The mutex object referenced by mutex shall be locked by calling pthread_mutex_lock(). If the mutex is already locked, the calling thread shall block until the mutex becomes available. This operation shall return with the mutex object referenced by mutex in the locked state with the calling thread as its owner.

In other words, upon return from `pthread_mutex_lock`, the mutex is "owned" by the thread.  The system guarantees that at most one thread can "own" a single mutex at any time.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should not be passing `pthread_mutex_t` around by value:

```
void testMutex(pthread_mutex_t myMutex)
```

Make that `pthread_mutex_t*`. Even though your code *might* work for you (which I doubt), it's not portable since `pthreads` types are meant to be opaque.

[There's a discussion of this in the relevant FAQ](http://www.lambdacs.com/cpt/FAQ.html#Q15). Among other things, it hints at the possibility that your use of `pthread_mutex_t` would result in **a copy of the mutex** being made each time `testMutex` is called (with the function locking the copy instead of the original mutex).

Once you've fixed this, the following will hold:

Since the two threads are using the same mutex, the second thread with block on either of the two `pthread_mutex_lock` calls for as long as the first thread is inside either of the two `pthread_mutex_lock`-`pthread_mutex_unlock` sections. The reverse is also true (the first thread will block for as long as the second thread has the mutex).

In other words, as long as one thread has a lock on a mutex, no other thread can lock the same mutex.

Comment: I don't think there are any implementations where this code will work. Instead `pthread_mutex_lock` will lock *a copy of* the mutex, which will not block other threads. Technically performing any operation on a copy of a mutex results in UB, but the behavior is almost surely as I just described for real implementations.

Comment: Actually the text in the FAQ you linked is wrong. Contrary to what it says, copying `pthread_t` is perfectly valid, and in fact all uses of `pthread_t` in the standard functions pass it by value (even if it is a structure) rather than by reference, except `pthread_create` where an address to store the result is passed. Of course `pthread_t` will normally itself be a pointer to an opaque data structure...

Answer (score 1):

thread2 will block in the pthread_mutex_lock() function until thread1 unlocks the mutex.

If not, what would the purpose of the mutex be in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

thread2 will stay blocked and won't be able to increment globalVarr++ until thread1 releases the mutex.

Answer (score 0):

The position in the function is not important - if one thread has the mutex, the other can't get it.